# ply lex delimit token reading by spaces

Tags: lexer, ply

I'm doing a basic lexical analyzer, for now I only want to read tokens in an input and print them, but the thing is, I want that if in the input there are two or more token coincidence found stuck together read them as an error, so for the coincidences to be found as true they have to be separated with a space blank, lets say I have to defined tokens as VAR and NUM, VAR is any a-z character, NUM is any 0-9 character, if input = 1a , then there is two coincidences 1 as NUM and a as VAR, but I need the analyzer to get it as an error, only as true if tokens are separated, like in input = 1 a , is there a way to do this?

```
tokens = [
    'NUMBER',
    'VAR'
]

def t_NUMBER(t):
    r'\d+\.?\d*'
    t.value = float(t.value)
    return t

def t_VAR(t):
    r'[a-z]+'
    t.value = str(t.value)
    return t

def t_ANY_error(t):
    print("ERROR", end = ' ')
    t.lexer.skip(1)

lexer = lex.lex()

input = 1a

lexer.input(input)

NUM_count = 0
VAR_count = 0
while True:
    token = lexer.token()
    if not token:
        break  # No hay más tokens

    elif token.type == "NUMBER":
        if str(token.value) not in token_array:
            token_array.append(str(token.value))
            print("{}{}".format(token.type, NUM_count), end = ' ')
            print(token.value)
            NUM_count = NUM_count + 1

        else:
            print("", end = ' ')

    elif token.type == "VAR":
        if str(token.value) not in token_array:
            token_array.append(str(token.value))
            print("{}{}".format(token.type, VAR_count), end = ' ')
            print(token.value)
            VAR_count = VAR_count + 1

        else:
            print("", end = ' ')
```

(Code is for example purposes)

Tried ignoring spaces and catch them as tokens too

Comment: I think you are not understanding the relationship between lexical analysis and parsing. If two lexical tokens are adjacent to each other, like NUMVAR then more normally that would become an identifier token; the parser would then report an error if the incorrect sequence of tokens was generated. You appear to be trying  to do the job of the parser in the lexer. Perhaps this is an XY problem...